# Strange javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Please take a look at this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Qstuw/7/

First answer is selected by default, when you enter to the page. Try to select second answer. Then return to 1st and select it again. I don't understand what am I missing, but I can't select first answer again. Any suggestion?

## UPDATE

Based on first answer:

True answer must be "switched" between answers. Like on SO. All other buttons must be enabled when you click on some active button and the button on whitch you have clicked must be disabled. Green border only on answer where you've clicked

Comment: You never set anything back the way it was; you only toggle "one-way".

Comment: You need to set the SelectedAnswerBtn again as its a new element now.. And SelectedAnswerBtn has the cached element currently..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't redeclare the button. Should get you closer

```
AnswerDiv.on("click", ".NotSelectedAnswer", function(){
    $(this).button("disable");

    SelectedAnswerBtn.removeClass("SelectedAnswer").addClass("NotSelectedAnswer").button("enable");
    $("div.Answer[data-id="+SelectedAnswerBtn.data("id")+"]").toggleClass("SelectedDiv");
    $("div.Answer[data-id="+$(this).data("id")+"]").toggleClass("SelectedDiv");

    NotSelectedAnswerBtn=$(".NotSelectedAnswer");
    NotSelectedAnswerBtn.button('enable');
SelectedAnswerBtn=$(".SelectedAnswer");
AnswerDiv=$("div.Answer");
})
```

Comment: @epic_syntax How about you take the gist of it and give it a shot? It's a one-line change once you get the buttons in their *current* state.

Comment: No it's absolutely not what I need. True answer must be "switched" between answers. Like on SO. All other buttons must be enabled when you click on some active button and the button on whitch you have clicked must be disabled. Green border only on answer where you've clicked

Comment: @epic_syntax Try. Without thinking about it at all; http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/zDR7r/1/ Thomas gave you the key to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Qstuw/24/) . I have made the required changes to make it work.. You are caching the objects and assigning them the new elements when the selection has been changed

//

```
 AnswerDiv.on("click", ".NotSelectedAnswer", function(){
        $(this).button("disable");
        NotSelectedAnswerBtn= $(".NotSelectedAnswer");
        SelectedAnswerBtn= $(".SelectedAnswer");
        SelectedAnswerBtn.removeClass("SelectedAnswer").addClass("NotSelectedAnswer").button("enable");
        NotSelectedAnswerBtn.removeClass("NotSelectedAnswer").addClass("SelectedAnswer").button("disable");
        $("div.Answer[data-id="+SelectedAnswerBtn.data("id")+"]").toggleClass("SelectedDiv");
        $("div.Answer[data-id="+$(this).data("id")+"]").toggleClass("SelectedDiv");
    })
```

Also make sure you assign the var to the local variables initially..  Its a good practice.